# What method should be followed to get html content along with drupal views

Tags: json, drupal-7, view

I am working with drupal 7 **views**.
I created a simple **CCK** which contains a title and a body . I added HTML content to body and selected Formater to **Full html**.
content sample :

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
  <p> This is a sample Text.</p>
  <p> To test the content </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also created a **VIEW (JSON document)** so that the content can be displayed on my iphone or android devices.

The problem is when i display the data on my phone it simply shows

```
This is a sample Text. /n To test the cotent
```

Now, Is it possible to get data same as text entered to content body?

Just like I should also show **html tags** too!
So that i can display the result in a Web view on my device(with out `/n` etc stuff).
[image]
Please Help !!

Thank you

This is the screen shot for Views settings.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edited after OP posted screenshot*

So, there are a few reasons why your HTML tags are being naturally stripped.

- One problem here is that you've selected JSON Data as your Format Type. JSON data documents are naturally not user-friendly, as they're intended simply to provide data to be consumed by other views. Try changing your Format to something else that's intended for end-user consumption. I like [Semantic Views](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews) a lot.

  - **EDIT:** If you're sticking with JSON Data, click "Settings" under the Format section and make sure the "Plaintext Output" and "Remove Newlines" checkboxes are unchecked.
- Secondly, you will indeed need to make sure that the individual Views Fields Formatter settings match your CCK Field Formatter settings. To see what I'm referring to, click "Content: Body" under the "Fields" section. You'll see a Formatter dropdown, which is most likely set to a default setting that isn't "Full HTML."

If you change those things, you should be good to go.

Comment: Already the setting is in Full HTML. Yes i need only in JSON document.And the individual field setting is also default

Comment: Ok, under "Settings" for your JSON Data type (the Settings link under the Format section in Views) is "Plaintext Output" checked? See my edit to the answer above...

Comment: Hi PJ , I tried checking "Plain Text" it displays "Body" : "\n\n\n\n\nTesting the Text formats\n\n\n"
The actual format is <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p>Testing the Text formats</p>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Settings screen?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the View's format settings. The screen that appears when you click the link next to "JSON Data Document."

Comment: Uncheck the boxes "Plaintext Output" and "Remove newlines," and see if the View behaves the way you want.

Comment: Woow such a simple task. Thanks a lot PJ. But why still /n appears at the end . I also checked remove whitespaces option

Comment: No problem, glad to help! /n is a newline character, so if you unchecked "Remove Newlines" this may be a bug. I'd recommend filing an issue in the JSON Data Formatter module's Issue queue on Drupal.org.